# How to declare handler for OnPointerEntered using cppwinrt?

Tags: c++-winrt

In cppwinrt (xaml not yet available) I have a handler for the PointerEntered event of a Button, and it works fine. But in attempting to remove the default hover behavior of this Button, which displays as an image, it seems I may need to handle the OnPointerEntered event instead - I have seen solutions that involve using a xaml trigger and this would seem to be a code equivalent. But OnPointerEntered has a different argument list, and I can't find a way to invoke it that will build. Here is how the PointerEntered event handle is successfully declared:

```
button.PointerEntered([&](winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const & sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const & args) { EnteredButton(); });
```

That builds and correctly calls EnteredButton. But

```
button.OnPointerEntered([&](winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::PointerRoutedEventArgs const & e)
{
    EnteredButton();
});
```

will not build - I am declaring it incorrectly but am not sure how, after trying a number of variants. (Using the fully-qualified names is maybe not necessary, but seems not to hurt in either case). Can OnPointerEntered be used in cppwinrt, and how would it be declared if so? I have tried using IPointerRoutedEventArgs instead of PointerRoutedEventArgs with no effect. Or - if anyone knows a different way to disable the hover effect in a Button created with cppwinrt, that would work.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but `PointerEntered` allows you to set up a delegate, called when the event is fired, whereas `OnPointerEntered` is implemented in `IControlOverridesT`, which strongly suggests, that it is a member you can override, and provide your own implementation. I don't know, but would assume, that `OnPointerEntered` is called by default, unless you set up a custom delegate using `PointerEntered`.

Comment: More information is available in the [On\* event handler overrides](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control#Remarks) topic.

Comment: What would be really great, given the frequency with which similar questions appear, would be for the Button to simply have a flag that would disable the hover effect.

Comment: Hang on, given your question history it sounds more like you haven't properly implemented rendering, which happens to show during the hover effect. The solution isn't to disable hovering, but to fix the rendering instead.

Comment: IInspectable - thanks but the buttons do work beautifully except for having the imagebrush disappear when the pointer enters. I've seen a great many xaml solutions offered for eliminating the hover effect, but no one has yet mentioned rendering, I think. Not to display my ignorance, but this is the first time I've heard any reference to a need to implement anything about rendering. Could you give a specific reference?

Comment: I don't have a reference. It just sounds implausible, that a button - likely one of the most common UI controls - would fail under certain, common conditions, like hovering. This sounds more like a styling issue, i.e. you have changed the normal state, but failed to adjust the hover state as well. No reference, though, and I could be wrong, too.

Comment: It's not failing - it's just doing what buttons normally do. I've set the Background to an ImageBrush so that it displays a bitmap image rather than text. And when the default hover effect is triggered, that disappears the  image and replaces it with the default hover brush for the duration of the hover. A number of people have asked how to prevent that from happening, but all the solutions I've seen involve creating a custom button template in xaml. What I'm looking for is a way to accomplish that in C++.

Comment: Sorry, can't move this to chat without more reputation. You mentioned adjusting the hover state. That is exactly what I'd like to know how to do programmatically in C++. Ideally hover would simply change the opacity of the image, or at least do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you're asking. Echoing IInspectable's comment:

- PointerEntered is an event on Windows::UI::Xaml::UIElement. Your code is correctly declaring a handler for it.
- OnPointerEntered is **not** an event, so there is no way to handle it. It is an overridable method for which you can provide your own implementation.

Comment: Thanks - I was using the wrong terminology. If it will help anyone else, I solved my problem this way: I created my own button class using StackPanel as the button body, and handled the PointerEntered, etc. events. The button has two ImageBrushes available, one for the on image and one for off. That way I can show a hover effect or not, as it pleases me. This uses a lambda and the arguments aren't needed: m_body.PointerEntered([&](winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const & sender, IPointerRoutedEventArgs const & args)
 {
  ButtonEntered();
 });